# Emoji-Slider like instagram + javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, instagram, web-component

I have this example with a `webComponent` written in `vueJs cli 3` (https://codesandbox.io/s/9j5mllm6lr) and it doesn't work, as you can see when you open the link

This is the example I have founded https://github.com/leofavre/emoji-slider, now I would like to transform it to a `vueJs` Component but doesn't work, or maybe if someone can explaine how to use it with `vueJs`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I know you can use native components in Vue. Do you really need to convert this one?

Comment: not really, but I would like to use it in my vuejs app, no matter how

Answer (score 0):

I would use this project: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-mart-vue.
You have to use set="google", as Instagram uses googles Emojiset. However unfortunately the library doesn't integrate itself into the textfield, you will have to find a solution for that and i only have an example for react.

Comment: I think not that this is the same which I mentioned above